# Easiest setup of email form on IIS 6 using PHP or ASP

Tags: forms, email, asp-classic, iis-6

I've tried several variations of ASP & PHP native & 3rd party mailer programs.  I have hit a wall at almost every point between setting ini parameters from within the scripts to permission denied/transport fails.

I would be wasting time to show my examples for what I've tried so far.  All my searches produce too many results with too many forums with too many 3rd party installations.  I want to find the simplest way to set this up.

I don't care about fancy html formatting, attachments, colors, radio buttons, check boxes, etc... I would just love to find something with one text form field and a submit button that upon clicking it will send a simple email to me.  I thought this would be a lot easier, but I never worked with IIS servers before.

A step by step approach or a link to a tested true resource would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

The closest I got, with the least cryptic of error messages was with this asp code from tizag...

```vb
<%
'Sends an email
Dim mail
Set mail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
mail.To = Request.Form("To")
mail.From = Request.Form("From")
mail.Subject = Request.Form("Subject")
mail.TextBody = Request.Form("Body")
mail.Send()
Response.Write("Mail Sent!")
'Destroy the mail object!
Set mail = nothing
%>
```

The error I get back is:

> CDO.Message.1 error '80040220'
>
> The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid.

Comment: The easiest way (for me) on IIS6 would be ASP.NET.  Is that an option?  If so, I'll post the steps and the code.

Comment: ill give it a shot... go for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ASP.NET:

Install ASP.NET - I will assume that you have version 2, 3, or 3.5 of .NET installed.
In a command prompt:

```
cd \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Create a file in the appropriate virtual directory (maybe inetpub\wwwroot?) called email.aspx with the following text:

```
<%@ Page language="c#"  %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
               "jane@contoso.com",
               FromEmail.Text,
               Subject.Text,
               Message.Text);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
        client.Send(message);
    }
</script>

<html>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>From Email:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox id="FromEmail" runat="server" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Subject:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox id="Subject" runat="server" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Message:</td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox id="Message" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><asp:Button id="SendButton" runat="Server" Text="Send" OnClick="SendButton_Click" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

You will need to change the string "127.0.0.1" to the IP address of your SMTP server and you will need to change the "jane@contoso.com" to the email address that you would like the mail sent to.

You could also require that the user enters an email address (and a valid one), a subject, and a message, by adding RequiredFieldValidator's and a RegularExpressionValidator.

Comment: Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Comment: Create a file called web.config with the following:
<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off">
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Answer (score 1):

Sending email in [ASP using the CDO.Message object](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp) is really easy.

Here's a more complex sample with error handling and email address validation.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<% Option Explicit %>
<%
    Dim bPostback : bPostback = request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST"
    Dim sResult : sResult = ""

    If bPostBack Then
        Dim sSmtpServer : sSmtpServer = "your.smtp.server"
        Dim sToEmail : sToEmail = "youremail@yourdomain.com"
        Dim sFromEmail : sFromEmail = request.Form("email")
        Dim sName : sName = request.Form("name")
        Dim sSubject : sSubject = request.Form("subject")
        Dim sBody : sBody = request.Form("body")

        Dim oEmailer : Set oEmailer = New Emailer

        oEmailer.SmtpServer = sSmtpServer
        oEmailer.FromEmail = sFromEmail
        oEmailer.ToEmail = sToEmail
        oEmailer.Subject = sSubject
        'oEmailer.HTMLBody = ""
        oEmailer.TextBody = sBody


        If oEmailer.sendEmail Then
            sResult = "Email sent!"
        Else
            sResult = "Something went terribly wrong!(" + oEmailer.ErrMsg + ")"
        End If
    End If

    'Simple Emailer
    Class Emailer
        Private oCDOM
        Public FromEmail
        Public ToEmail
        Public Subject
        Public HTMLBody
        Public TextBody
        Public SmtpServer
        Public Port
        Public ErrMsg

        Private Sub Class_Initialize()
            Set oCDOM = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

            TextBody = ""
            'HTMLBody = ""
            Port = 25
        End Sub

        'SQL IsNull equivalent
        Private Function ifNull(vVar1, vVar2)
            If Not IsNull(vVar1) Then
                ifNull = vVar1
            Else
                ifNull = vVar2
            End If
        End Function

        'Verifies that the Email address conforms to RFC standard.
        Public Function isEmail(emailStr)
            isEmail = False
            If IsNull(emailStr) Then Exit Function

            Dim emailPat : emailPat = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-])+(\.([a-zA-Z0-9_\-])+)*@((\[(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5])))\.(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5])))\.(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5])))\.(((([0-1])?([0-9])?[0-9])|(2[0-4][0-9])|(2[0-5][0-5]))\]))|((([a-zA-Z0-9])+(([\-])+([a-zA-Z0-9])+)*\.)+([a-zA-Z])+(([\-])+([a-zA-Z0-9])+)*))$"
            Dim loRE : Set loRE = New RegExp

            loRE.IgnoreCase = True
            loRE.Global = True
            loRE.Pattern = emailPat

            If loRE.Test(emailStr) Then isEmail = True
            Set loRE = Nothing
        End Function

        Public Function sendEmail()
            sendEmail = True

            'On Error Resume Next

            If IfNull(SmtpServer,"") = "" Then sendEmail = False
            If Not isEmail(FromEmail) Then sendEmail = False
            If Not isEmail(ToEmail) Then sendEmail = False
            If IfNull(Trim(Subject),"") = "" Then sendEmail = False
            If IfNull(Trim(HTMLBody),"") = "" And IfNull(Trim(TextBody),"") = "" Then sendEmail = False
            If sendEmail = False Then Exit Function

            oCDOM.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
            oCDOM.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")=SmtpServer
            oCDOM.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=CINT(Port)
            oCDOM.Configuration.Fields.Update

            oCDOM.From = FromEmail
            oCDOM.To = ToEmail
            oCDOM.Subject = Subject
            'oCDOM.HTMLBody = "<div>" & HTMLBody & "<div>"
            oCDOM.TextBody = TextBody

            oCDOM.Send

            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                ErrMsg = Err.description
                Err.Clear
                sendEmail = False
                Exit Function
            Else
                sendEmail = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        End Function

        Private Sub Class_Terminate()
            Set oCDOM = Nothing
        End Sub
    End Class
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Emailer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><strong><%=sResult%></strong></p>    
        <form action="" method="post" target="_self">
            <label for="name">Name:</label><input id="name" name="name" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50" />
            <br />
            <label for="email">Email:</label><input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="50" maxlength="1024" />
            <br />
            <label for="subject">Subject:</label><input id="subject" name="subject" type="text" size="50" maxlength="1024" />
            <br />
            <label for="body">Body:</label>
            <br />
            <textarea id="body" name="body"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input name="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'

The transport failed to connect to the server.

Comment: Stupid question, did you replace "your.smtp.server" on Line 8 with your SMTP server?  Does your SMTP server require authentication to send email?

Comment: yeah haha... dont know about the auth... were going to check over the server settings on monday

Answer (score 1):

For your ASP example, I think you are just missing the smtp server configuration:

```
<%
'Sends an email
Dim mail
Set mail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
mail.To = Request.Form("To")
mail.From = Request.Form("From")
mail.Subject = Request.Form("Subject")
mail.TextBody = Request.Form("Body")

mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.server.com"
'Server port
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
mail.Configuration.Fields.Update


mail.Send()
Response.Write("Mail Sent!")
'Destroy the mail object!
Set mail = nothing
%>
```

As in the ASP.NET example, you would need to change "smtp.server.com" to your SMTP server's IP address.

Comment: Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a01a8'

Object required: 'myMail'

Comment: Fixed above.  Sorry for the typo's

Answer (score 1):

PHP:
use the builtin mail (...) method.  If your not doing anything fancy you can use it directly.

Example:

```
form.php
<?php
if($_REQUEST['action']=='mail'){
    $to="toaddress@gmail.com";
    $from="fromaddress@gmail.com";
    $subject="this is my subject";
    $body=$_POST['body'];
    $headers="From: $from\r\nTo: $to\r\nSubject: $subject\r\n";

    if (stristr($to,"Content-Type")||stristr($subject,"Content-Type")||stristr($body,"Content-Type")||stristr($headers,"Content-Type")) {
           header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
           echo "YOU HAVE BEEN BANNED FROM ACCESSING THIS SERVER FOR TRIGGERING OUR SPAMMER TRAP";
           exit;
    }

    if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
         echo("Succesfully mailed to $to");
         exit();
    }else{
         echo("Failed to send mail<br>");
    }         
}
?>
<form method=post>
    <input type=hidden name=action value=mail>
    <textarea name=body rows=4 cols=40><?php echo($_POST['body']); ?></textarea>
    <input type=submit value=Send>
</form>
```

PS: The Content-Type check is to prevent someone from hijacking your email form.

PSS: This will use the mailserver as set in php.ini, that is the only setting that should matter.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me using ASP Classic: http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp

```
Dim ObjSendMail
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

'This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.

ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="remoteserver"
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False 'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60


ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

'End remote SMTP server configuration section==

ObjSendMail.To = "test@test.com"
ObjSendMail.Subject = "this is the subject"
ObjSendMail.From = "someone@someone.net"

' we are sending a text email.. simply switch the comments around to send an html email instead
'ObjSendMail.HTMLBody = "this is the body"
ObjSendMail.TextBody = "this is the body"

ObjSendMail.Send

Set ObjSendMail = Nothing
```